# Visual Studio Project - Is it possible to Embed files(css, js, cshtml) on Release mode but not on Debug mode?

Tags: c#, optimization

I need to know if it is possible to apply a special configuration in a VS project to have embedded files (css, js, cshtml) only on Release mode, but when in Debug mode it will not work as embedded, this way I can quickly work over a *.cshtml and refresh the screen without having to re-compile the application.

Right now we have a project with all those embedded resources but it causes slow development process because any small change we need to do requires to re-compile the application, and given that is a huge solution with many projects, the process to save, compile and re-build and start in debug mode takes a lot of time to test that small fix.

I hope I was clear on what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: Why not splitting solution into many solutions and reference only the assembly?

Comment: @SebastianSchulz that would still require a recompilation, the OP wouldn't be able to change it during debug time and see his modifications

Comment: What kind of project is that ? ASP.NET ? If it is, you should check out the `BrowserLink` functionality of VS

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171482.aspx

Comment: @Sidewinder94, thanks a lot for the suggestion. Meanwhile the BrowserLink will improve our process. Performing some test I was able to get changes reflected in the screen in half of the time by using the BrowserLink capability.

Thanks.